# Python Mechanize Form submit

Tags: python, linux, forms, mechanize

I am trying to log into a web-page where with member number (medlemsnummer) and postal code (postnummer) with mechanize.

```
br = Browser()
br.open('http://www.bokklubben.no/SamboWeb/medlem/minSide.do')

br.select_form(nr=1)

br.form['loggInn'] = '123456'
br.form['passord'] = '0202'

br.submit()
```

It seems that it's just loading and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has a name, `LoginForm`. So you should select it like so:

```
br.select_form("LoginForm")
```

Also the name of the first form field is `login` not `loggInn` so you use

```
br.form['login'] = '123456'
```